# How to loop through a mysql array and create another array with its content depending on a variable $i

Tags: php, mysql, json, loops

I'm trying to make a loop in php that will go through a MySQL array and fetch some information depending on a variable.

The table in MySQL is like so: id,slot1,slot2,slot3,...slot12.

```
$max_player_slots = 5;

//***Create Inventory Array**//

    $inventory_info = "SELECT * from inventory where id = $player_id";
    $inventory_info2 = mysql_query($inventory_info) or die ("Couldn't get inventorys    stats");
    $inventory_info3 = mysql_fetch_array($inventory_info2);


//depending on max player slots insert that many values into &invSlots array

    for( $i = 1, $invSlots = array(); $i > $max_player_slots; $i++){

        $invSlots[$i] = $inventory_info3[$i]; //here is the problem i dont know how to insert the diferent values using $i

    }


        $json = $invSlots;
        $encoded = json_encode($json);
        die ($encoded);
```

I would expect the $invSlots array after this to contain:

```
$invSlots = array(slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5);
```

but I just get an error.

I think the reason is because the mysql array information is stored in an associative array and im trying to access it numericly? but I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: "but I just get an error."... what error?

Comment: I dont get an error message it just doesnt work it seems like it goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't it be

```
for( $i = 1, $invSlots = array(); $i < $max_player_slots; $i++){
```

`<` instead of `>`?

Comment: Well this is very embarrasing...sry for wasting yout time I checked it so many times I just got blocked.

Comment: no problem ;) sometimes I have the same problem and waste hours for solving such simple things